# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope' with Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to run a script, but I struggle already at the imports.
This import

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import save_img
```

raises the following error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'.
```

I am using the following packages.

```
Keras                     2.2.2,                     
Keras-Applications        1.0.4,                   
Keras-Preprocessing       1.0.2,                   
tensorflow                1.9.0,                     
tensorflow-gpu            1.9.0
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce with the same versions of the keras and tensorflow, reinstalling keras and tensorflow, may solve the issue, please use commands below:

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
pip install -I tensorflow
pip install -I keras
```

**NOTE**: The `-I` parameter stands for ignore installed package.

Comment: Just to add to this answer, name_scope should indeed be included with tf 1.9.0 so it seems that there is something fishy with the installation.

Comment: @VegardKT thanks, yes, it's available for sure, I bet it's installation issues to.

Comment: But Why? I was using this environment for a week now to build models in keras. Maybe because I installed tensorflow serving today?

Comment: I get the error "ImportError: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow`" when following these instructions.

Comment: @user3367130 I think you have installed older tensorflow version at some point, you can check versions with pip freeze

Answer (score 4):

For everyone who use Tensorflow 2.0 and stumble upon this question with the same error, like I did: I solved it by changing the imports from `keras.xxx` to `tensorflow.keras.xxx`

Answer (score 1):

I also encountered this same problem when I stopped my IDE while executing. Restarting my IDE works for me. Just save your program and restart IDE. Hope it will work for you as well.

Answer (score 0):

As [Andriy Ivaneyko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2067976/andriy-ivaneyko) mentioned above, reinstalling `tensorflow` helps. I'm not sure why, but installing `tensorflow-serving-api` breaks something somewhere along the way. We solved this by running:

```
pip install --force-reinstall tensorflow
```

Note that this applies to both `tensorflow` and `tensorflow-gpu` installations. Specifically, the above command will fix this problem in situations where you're specifically using `tensorlfow-gpu`. `tensorflow-serving-api` installs regular `tensorflow` if it's not already installed.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this same bug and reinstalling tensorflow made no difference, and this caused me some headscratching.

Eventually I noticed that my IDE autocomplete had added the following line to my code:

```
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```

It seems that directly referencing `tensorflow_core.python` will break `tensorflow`.

Replacing this with the normal tensorflow import solved the problem!

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
```

Answer (score 0):

My IDE offered me two different import paths

```
keras
```

or

```
tensorflow_core.python.keras
```

In my example I could either import like this:

```
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, Input, Activation
from keras import optimizers, Model
```

or like that:

```
from tensorflow_core.python.keras import Input, Model, optimizers
from tensorflow_core.python.keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense
```

Mixing up tensorflow_core.python.keras and plain keras led to the problem in my case. After I imported everything directly from keras and keras.layers, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

My tensorflow version is 2.1, and I found my tensorflow-estimator version is 2.2

My fix is to downgrade the estimator to the same version