# Keras + Tensorflow: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Importing from Keras:

```
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences
```

gives an error:

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'

I'm using MacOs/Anaconda/Python 3.6:

Keras                     2.2.4,
Keras-Applications        1.0.6,
Keras-Preprocessing       1.0.5,
tensorflow                1.12.0,

i've read [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724309/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-name-scope-with-keras) - doesn't help (((
tried reinstall Anaconda - no effect. 
But i have some clue, maybe problem connected with Python version?

```
python --version
```

gives 3.6.8, but in Anaconda3/lib/ only Python3.7

Comment: Please include the full backtrace. Did you name any of your scripts as tensorflow.py?

Comment: Please check in Latest version and also make sure that there is no custom built tensorflow.py file in your folder.                                                                      
Reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545273/tensorflow-2-0-beta-has-no-attribute-keras