# Tensorflow 2.0 beta has no attribute keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Keras doesnt seems to be installed. I am using the Tensorflow 2.0 beta.

I've already tried to reinstall Tensorflow. I've seen multiple similar threads, however none of them helped

I get the error
"AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'keras'" when I try to access tf.keras.

For Example:

import tensorflow as tf

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

Comment: did you try to remove all other TF versions?

Comment: Installing with `pip install tensorflow-gpu==2.0.0-beta` works fine for me, notice that `tf.keras` is included so, you do not need to install `keras` separately.

Comment: Does importing any other submodule work? Dou you have any files in your project called `tensorflow.py`? If so, rename them.

Comment: There was a tensorflow.py file. Thanks