# Error while importing img_to_array function: AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'

Tags: python, keras, data-science, tensorflow2.0

So I am new to Keras and Tensorflow. I'm trying to import the `img_to_array` function and for some reason it is not importing it. I read the documentation it says `from PIL import Image` and after that use `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(img)` and that doesn't work either. I am using anaconda.

Here's the code:

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import img_to_array
```

And here's the error:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name_scope'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'name\_scope' with Keras](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51724309/attributeerror-module-tensorflow-has-no-attribute-name-scope-with-keras)

Comment: Which version of keras and tensorflow are you using?

Comment: I'm using Tensorflow 2.1.0 and Version 2.3.1 of Keras.

Comment: @Liorr I looked at that but no luck.....

Comment: @Hamza Even the second (not accepted) answer?

Comment: @Liorr no mate. I tried from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import array_to_img but the error I got was,  No module named 'tensorflow.keras.preprocessing'; 'tensorflow.keras' is not a package

Comment: And one more thing. The imports I have mentioned in the problem actually works fine on Google Colab. But these same doesn't work on Jupyter Notebook. I'm really frustrated. It's been 2 days and I'm stuck on these imports